# Kotlin - Unique Characters in String

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, unique

My function should return a boolean indicating whether the input String contains all unique characters.

e.g.
"abc" returns true, "abca" returns false

```
fun uniqueCharacters(s: String): Boolean = s.groupBy { it }
    .values
    .stream()
    .allMatch { it.size == 1 }
```

Is there a more efficient way of solving this problem? If I was solving this in non-functional way I would store all the characters in a Map with the value being the count of that character so far, if it is greater than one then break and return false.

Not sure how best to translate this into a functional Kotlin piece of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) function and `Set::add` as predicate for it

```
fun main() {
    println("abc".allUnique()) // true
    println("abca".allUnique()) // false
}

fun String.allUnique(): Boolean = all(hashSetOf<Char>()::add)
```

It's lazy, the function returns the result when it finds the first duplicate

Comment: Nice! I haven't before seen this pattern of instantiating a temporary collection for its method reference all in one go.

Comment: Can I ask how you would write this as a non-extension function?

Comment: @h1h1 `fun allUnique(s: String): Boolean = s.all(hashSetOf<Char>()::add)`

Comment: That's a nice solution for sure +1

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the simplest way is to create a `Set` of the characters, and check its size:

```
fun String.isUniqueCharacters() = toSet().size == length
```

(Since this function depends only on the contents of the string, it seems logical to make it an extension function; that makes it easier to call, too.)

As for performance, it's effectively creating a hash table of the characters, and then checking number of entries, which is the number of unique characters.  So that's not trivial.  But I can't think of a way which is significantly better.

Other approaches might include:

- Copying the characters to an array, sorting it in-place, and then scanning it comparing adjacent elements.  That would save some memory allocation, but needs more processing.
- As above, but using a hand-coded sort algorithm that spots duplicates and returns early.  That would reduce the processing in cases where there *are* duplicates, but at the cost of much more coding.  (And the hand-coded sort would probably be slower than a library sort when there *aren't* duplicates.)
- Creating an array of 65536 booleans (one for every possible `Char` value<sup>*</sup>), all initialised to false, and then scanning through each character in the string checking the corresponding array value (returning false if it was already set, else setting it).  That would probably be the fastest approach, but takes a lot of memory.  (And the cost of initialising the array could be significant.)

As always, it comes down to trading off memory, processing, and coding effort.

<sup>(* There are of course many more characters than this in Unicode, but Kotlin uses UTF-16 internally, so 65536 is all we need.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach

```
fun String.uniqueCharacters(): Boolean = this.toCharArray().distinct().isNotEmpty()
```